# online grep while generating output

Tags: bash, grep

I want to run a program which writes some outputs to a file. Now in this file, I will grep for certain strings and write them to another file. I don't want to serialize the process. Instead I want to pipe the commands. However this command doesn't work

```
./run_prog | grep READ > read_data.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this command doesn't work"? If ``run_prog`` is executable and writes to standard output, you should get all lines containing ``READ`` in ``read_data.txt``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned, sounds like your program might be writing to STDERR instead of STDOUT.  To make sure you capture that as well, try this:

```
./run_prog 2>&1 | grep READ > read_data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your `./run_prog` gives your output to STDOUT. The following example shows that it should work.

```
$>echo "READ" | grep READ > read_data.txt
$>cat read_data.txt
READ
$>
```

Since you are now assured it should work debug by just running `./run_prog` then add `| grep`.

Comment: ah yes. I redirected the output to stderr!!